# Opening non-TXT text file with jQuery AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am attempting to load or read a text file with an extension other than .txt, specifically .log . My code will read and display the file if it has a .txt extension but the same file when changed to a .log extension returns a 404 Not Found error.

```
$.ajax({
url: "http://servername/Logs/Documents/jan.Log",
type: "GET",
dataType: "text",
processData: false,
success: function(result){
 alert(result);
}
});
```

I can't seem to find the reason or any information on this issue.

Comment: Are you sure this file with that exact URL exist on the server and you can access it?

Comment: I second Dekel's question. You say "specifically .log" in the text, but .Log in the code.

Comment: and is this on same domain as the page you call it from?

Comment: Whatever the case, JavaScript doesn't care about the extension. This is a problem with the URL or the server configuration.

Comment: Yes, both files are valid and on the same server, same folder. To test, I made a copy of the .log file on the same folder and renamed the copy to .txt. Both files are identical except for the extension and the txt file opens but the .log file returns a 404 not found error, very odd